# Node Red Dashboard Include Images

Tags: node.js, node-red

I'm creating an application using `node-red` and creating the ui with `node-red-dashboard`.

I have included some api calls and based on the response I want to change the Image source of the template control.

`<img src="/home/pi/Destkop/WeatherImages/sun.png">`

So I used the absolute path to the image. But the image isn't get loaded. There is a symbol which indicates that and the source of the image is set to `localhost:1880/sun.png`.

Where do I need to place the Image? What Path do I need to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use local paths for files served from the web server built into Node-RED as the browser accessing the page may not be on the same machine that Node-RED is running on.

In the `settings.js` file (which will be in ~/.node-red) there is a setting called `httpStatic` you can use this to specify a directory that Node-RED will server up static content from.

```
...
// When httpAdminRoot is used to move the UI to a different root path, the
// following property can be used to identify a directory of static content
// that should be served at http://localhost:1880/.
//httpStatic: '/home/nol/node-red-static/',
...
```

If you set that to /home/pi/Destkop/WeatherImages as follows:

```
...
// When httpAdminRoot is used to move the UI to a different root path, the
// following property can be used to identify a directory of static content
// that should be served at http://localhost:1880/.
httpStatic: '/home/pi/Desktop/WeatherImages',
...
```

you can then set the image src as follows:

```
<img src="/sun.png">
```

Comment: Worked after setting `httpAdminRoot` from default `false` to `true` - looked it up in the documentation: http://nodered.org/docs/configuration

Comment: The dashboard tries to display `http://raspberrypi.local:1880/ui/sun.png` even when I specify `<img src="/sun.png">`.

Comment: That is most likely a caching issue